# Compile C++ Source Generated by HipHop

Tags: php, c++, compilation, hiphop

How can I compile a project converted into C++ with HipHop on a different server (which doesn't have HipHop installed)?

I've copied the source over, it look like this:

```
./   CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  CodeError.js  php/      sep_extensions.mk
../  CMakeFiles/     CMakeLists.txt       Makefile      sys/
```

Now how can I compile this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's got a `Makefile` in the directory; try just typing `make` and see what happens.

Comment: It says: `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/ec2-user/Predict" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1`

Comment: I'm going to go through the makefiles and update the paths, and see what it says then.

Comment: Now it says: `CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /root/Predict/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/ec2-user/Predict where CMackeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source "/root/Predict/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/home/ec2-user/Predict/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1`

Comment: I'm impressed -- it recognized that the situation has changed and recommended an approach to take! Cool. Try fiddling with the `CMakeCache.txt` file and try to make small enough changes that allow it to be built on your new environment.

Comment: Oh dear... I see that it's looking for all the HipHop libraries and such things. Looks like there is no way to compile it without installing HipHop.